# How to recode a variable based on the value of another variable?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, switch-statement, recode

Let's say I have this data frame.

```
df <- data.frame(record = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"),
                 fruit = c("apple", "orange", "other", "apple", "orange", "other"),
                 specify = c("", "", "red delicious", "", "", "navel"))
```

How do I recode the values of "other" in the fruit column to be "apple," or "orange" based on the values of the specify column? The red delicious record, 3, should be an apple, and the navel record, 6, should be orange in the fruit column, respectively.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `dplyr` version >= 1.1.0, we can use `case_match`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(fruit = case_match(specify, 
                                 "red delicious" ~ "apple", 
                                 "navel" ~ "orange", 
                                 .default = fruit))

  record  fruit       specify
1      1  apple              
2      2 orange              
3      3  apple red delicious
4      4  apple              
5      5 orange              
6      6 orange         navel
```

Comment: Thank you! Would anyone know why I am unable to overwrite my existing df, even if I start with df2 <- df2 %>% mutate(fruit = case_match(specify...

Comment: @BDuff Did `df2 %>% mutate(fruit = case_match(specify...` give you the correct output in the console? Is there any error? Note that my solution requires `dplyr` version newer than 1.1.0, if you have an older version, either update your `dplyr` or use @Maël's `case_when` :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Truth be told, both case_when and case_match work just fine with the example dataset, but when I tried to do apply this solution to my actual dataset (1313 observations, 227 variables), the column in question remains unchanged. I think it was because I had a ton of leading blank spaces in my real data. Once I removed those, I was good to go!

Comment: Update: removing spaces worked. This is so cool! THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

With `case_when`:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(fruit = case_when(specify == "red delicious" ~ "apple",
                           specify == "navel" ~ "orange", 
                           TRUE ~ fruit))

  record  fruit       specify
1      1  apple              
2      2 orange              
3      3  apple red delicious
4      4  apple              
5      5 orange              
6      6 orange         navel
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if using case statements is the most efficient way for lookups, consider 7500 varieties of apples alone wordwide. Adding new varieties or fruits is not nice when you have to do that in your code.

My approach would be:

```
# can just be a spreadsheet you read in as a data.frame
varieties <- data.frame(specify = c("red delicious", "navel"), fruit = c("apple", "orange"))

df %>%
  filter(fruit == "other") %>%
  select(1, 3) %>% 
  left_join(varieties, by = "specify") %>%
  bind_rows(df %>% filter(fruit != "other")) %>%
  arrange(record)

# record       specify  fruit
# 1      1                apple
# 2      2               orange
# 3      3 red delicious  apple
# 4      4                apple
# 5      5               orange
# 6      6         navel orange
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `fcase`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, fruit := fcase(specify == "red delicious", "apple",
  specify == "navel", "orange", !specify %chin% c("red delicious", "navel"), fruit )]
```